# Use boost or std to get the current local time in a specific timezone

Tags: c++, c++11, boost

Is it possible to use Boost libraries or std to get the current time in a specific timezone without knowing the offset but only the TZ?

For example: What is the current local time in "Europe/Rome"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### C++20 Update

If your vendor implements this part of C++20, this can now be done without a 3rd party lib:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << std::chrono::zoned_time{"Europe/Rome", std::chrono::system_clock::now()} << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/I0xueuIqd3u8QoPX)

### Original post

This is a one-liner with [Howard Hinnant's free, open-source, cross-platform, C++11/14 timezone library](https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html):

```
#include "date/tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::cout << date::make_zoned("Europe/Rome", std::chrono::system_clock::now()) << '\n';
}
```

This just output for me:

```
2017-11-29 16:24:32.710766 CET
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid any extra library but this one makes things much simpler than all others. Most probably, I will go with this library.

Comment: If it helps, this library is being proposed for a future C++ standard.  It may not make it, but currently the odds are 60/40 in favor.  It will be several years before you see it in `<chrono>` (2020 at best).  But I'm working on it...

Comment: is this a single header file that I can use in my CMake project?

Comment: No, the time zone support requires some installation:  https://howardhinnant.github.io/date/tz.html#Installation  There is a single source file, and there are options for using your OS's time zone database, or downloading one straight from the IANA website, either manually or automatically.  The project is currently developing CMake support.

Answer (score 2):

check this: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.datetime-location-dependent-times

```
#include <boost/date_time/local_time/local_time.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::local_time;
using namespace boost::posix_time;
using namespace boost::gregorian;

int main()
{
    time_zone_ptr tz{new posix_time_zone{"CET+1"}};
    ptime pt{date{2014, 5, 12}, time_duration{12, 0, 0}};
    local_date_time dt{pt, tz};
    std::cout << dt.utc_time() << '\n';
    std::cout << dt << '\n';
    std::cout << dt.local_time() << '\n';
    std::cout << dt.zone_name() << '\n';
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2014-May-12 12:00:00 
2014-May-12 13:00:00 CET 
2014-May-12 13:00:00 
CET
```